# Google Sheets - Lookup - Multiple lookups, with IF and OFFSET's

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I have a small club with my brothers that play golf, where we pay some money depending on how well our rounds go.
When we are done, I enter the scores, fairway hits and putts into a sheet that looks like the one I have attached below.

[The Tee Club - Scorecard Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6BKA.png)

Now, what I am trying to make is a statistics sheets that calculates our average fairway hits, putts etc..
I have that figured out.
But my problem is how to access the data with a formula that I can use for all of us, without having to make too many changes every time. If that makes sense..

Anyway, so far I have this formula:
`=IF((OFFSET(HLOOKUP("Mikkel";E3:P28;5;False);0;1;1;1))<=0;"";OFFSET(HLOOKUP("Mikkel";E3:P28;26;False);0;1;1;1))`

As it is right there, it searches for "Mikkel" in E3:P28, goes down 5, checks if it's blank or not, if not, it shows the value in F28.

All of this is perfect, except I would like to include a search for "Match 1" and then be able to find the same cell (F28) within that area, but if I change "Match 1", to "Match 2", it should lookup the value of W28 (I know that area is called "Turnering: Februar", but I'll change it). It will contain a total of 18 scorecards listed below and not only those 2 you see on the image.

I'm not quite sure how to explain what I want in any other way, so I really hope that someone can help me..

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance.
// Mikkel Christensen

**Edit**: Link for the sheet: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SFckCG_df4s60JeuS-g-PfKHv9gq2I1b_SI_lP3mDS0

Comment: Can you provide an example spreadsheet? That'll make it much easier to help

Comment: @RobinGertenbach ofcourse. :D
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SFckCG_df4s60JeuS-g-PfKHv9gq2I1b_SI_lP3mDS0](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SFckCG_df4s60JeuS-g-PfKHv9gq2I1b_SI_lP3mDS0)

Hope that works.., it's in the "Scorekort - 2017" sheet.

Comment: Anyone who can help? :D